# How can i get (keys,values) from an array contentvalue in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-asynctask, threadpool

I speak a little english, sorry if its hard to read.

This is my problem. I did a class extending Asyntask to set values to a database.
But the paremeter I set in generic types was ContentValues.

```
class putInformationToDB extends AsyncTask<ContentValues, Integer, Integer>
```

Then when I call the execute method to run it, I set a contentvalues that I made previously to get all the values from registry and dialogs.
But now in the method:

```
protected Integer doInBackground(ContentValues... params)
```

I have a problem. The paremeter is a array contentvalues, and I don't know how to take values/key back. If it was a contentvalues, I would take the values back with iterator, and map. But I don't know how to transform it in a contentvalues first. :-(

I was thinking about to pass another kind of parameter like String and then get it with a loop and put it in a ContentValues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply iterate over the array:

```
for(ContentValues c : params){
    //do something with c
}
```

or if you're sure that there is only an element in the array you can access it directly:

```
ContentValues c = params[0];
```

Comment: Thanks. Well, i was confused.

Comment: Its a little bit late but i get "foreach is not applicable for contentvalues"

Comment: You must bear in mind that the iteration is made through an array of ContentValues, not through a specific ContentValues. To iterate through a ContentValues you must use : 

for(Entry<String, Object> entry: contentValues.valueSet()){
...
}

Answer (score 1):

if you've passed an array. You may simply get it using
 ` ContentValues[] arr = params[0];

Answer (score 1):

To get the keys from [ContentValues](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues) use a for to get every Key set:

```
    ContentValues c = new ContentValues();
    ...
    ...
    for(String key : response.keySet()){
       System.out.println("key : " + key);       
    }
```

But if you want to get the value of each key into the [ContentValue](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues), use the method [get(String key)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html#get(java.lang.String)):

```
    for(String key : response.keySet()){
       System.out.println("key : " + key + " value: " + response.get(key));       
    }
```